# How to get Castle MonoRail's DataBinder/SmartDispatcherController to bind against types containing properties that are interfaces?

Tags: linq-to-sql, castle-monorail, databinder

We're using interfaces to represent entity classes in our domain model.  We have concrete implementations of these by virtue of using LinqToSql.  We have added a factory method to each LinqToSql class which our service layer uses to instantiate a new entity (note; as opposed to the controller's DataBind attribute doing it).

MonoRail's default DataBinder implementation will ignore properties that are defined as interfaces.

Ideally, we don't want to instantiate our data-layer classes in MonoRail - the whole point of the interfaces is to separate these concerns.

Also, we don't really want to create another set of non-LinqToSql concrete classes whose only job is to translate between layers.

It's the end of a **really** long day over here; please can someone have mercy and point us at the parts of IDataBinder that we should overload with our own implementations, or hint at other approaches we might attempt?  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking at IParameterBinder.  take a look at [a post I've written on the subject](http://www.kenegozi.com/Blog/2008/09/15/creating-a-custom-parameter-binder-for-monorail-actions-iparameterbinder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Ken pointed, your idea could be implemented with a custom IParameterBinder.

A solution would be to use IOC:

- resolve concrete instance of the form from it's interface
- then use IDataBinder to bind the instance to the request params

Another one would be using IDictionaryAdapter:

- generate a dto proxy for your interface
- then use IDataBinder to bind the dto proxy instance to the request params

NB: second option won't work if interface:

- is not public (hum)
- has methods
- or events
- or readonly properties
- or setonly properties

Last, I'm unsure of what is the problem exposing concrete class in controller's signature.

I myself use concrete form in controllers implementing interface defined in application layer services, it allows me to have concerns separated on both side:

- controller side is Http mapping and first level data validation of the form/command
- application layer services is business validation and processing of the form/command

Comment: At the time, I was committing the sin of binding to my entity classes directly, which happened to be interfaced.  I stopped doing that ;-)